# Azure appservice "Any data outside '/home' is not persisted"

Tags: php, apache, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to integrate php with oracle database which is running in Azure app service. For this there are some steps need to perform which requires changes OCI8. But, when I try to open SSH for this appservice I am seeing below message and not persisting any changes which I made outside of '/home' folder. Can someone help me out to how to persist changes made through ssh.

[image]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text (use formatting options). Also see [ask]. And lastly, I sense a [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364505): You might want to rephrase your question with the underlying problem, because the data in /home is not persisted, no matter what you do. That's a limitation that you get from certain cloud services: They're providing what they're providing. Rent your own server if you don't like those restrictions, or pick a different service

Comment: Try ssh in as username root